# Installing printer drivers it freezes up

Tags: drivers, printing, crash, epson

Its just a problem with installing the printer from Epson using the configure printer program. It just freezes half way through instillation.

I've been working on this problem or ages now I've tried everything from un-installing Software centre and Configure Printer programs. Each time it just stalls, then when I look in Software centre i can see packages half way installed. I've ran every script I can get my hands on. 
What is the command to find what the problem/error is?
It started when I accidentally rebooted half way through its original install

Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

once I clear this problem it occurs again when I try and Install the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I solved the problem, ON MY OWN, I might add! As a Nubie I was well excited!

I found the driver name, on first installing, it asked you which driver you want the Epson one the Ubuntu one or the Standard generic driver. It comes up with its name before you press accept.

Then I remembered the terminal normally sorts stuff out or tells you what code to type or an error code to go and look for/

You experts would probably say "well duh, obviously" but coming from windows you expect the graphical interfaces to work. 
I typed

```
sudo apt-get install epson-inkjet-printer-nx420
```

Then went back in to Printer Configuration and selected my printer, which was showing up in a handy icon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried purging the package like this

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove {package_name}
```

and re-installing again

you can also try this

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

if that dosen't work try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: I cant find the name of the packet, would a drive be called a packet, epson-nx420 is the name of the driver i'm trying to install.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package epson-nx420

Comment: i assume by packet you mean package...i thought you said you could see the package was half installed.the package should have a name

Comment: It just says Installing Packages Applying Changes nothing else.